# Once upon a time

Tags: grammar, articles

> *Once upon a time*

why there is an indefinite article in this sentence before the word time?

I am a newbie in learning the English language and my native language doesn't have any articles.

Comment: Why would there not be? It is an archaic fixed phrase used to start children's stories, which are supposed to be about something that happened once, at **a** time.

Comment: The full OED defines **on a time** - *on one occasion, once; = once upon a time at once, adv. A.I.2b. Now archaic and literary.* In a somewhat circular fashion, they define **once upon a time** - *at some time in the past (frequently as a conventional opening of a narrative), esp. a long time ago. Also as n. and attributive…*

Comment: See [What is the origin of once upon 
 a time idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466847/what-is-the-origin-of-the-once-upon-a-time-idiom-as-the-way-to-begin-a-fairy-t)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us how much you already know about the differences between indefinite and definite articles as they apply to this sentence, and what you're still unsure about.

Comment: In my native language their is no articles

Answer (score 2):

There are a few archaic phrases from earlier forms of English that have survived into modern English as idiomatic phrases. "Once upon a time" is one such phrase. Oxford notes that this phrase has been in use since around 1380 and in its current form since 1600.

Native speakers don't analyse it in terms of modern grammar; we just know that it broadly means "*once, at an unknown time*", or "*on a certain occasion*". The inference is that the events happened in a time unknown, to convey a sense of mystery, so it makes a degree of sense that it uses the indefinite article because it is not referring to a definite time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as strange a phrase as it may seem to be at first glance.  The only truly unusual element, I would say, is the preposition **upon**, and even that isn't as far from modern use at it might seem to be.

**time** is used there just as we use the word today:

> Remember the time you came to school with your shirt on inside out?
>
> I can't remember a time when that clock in the town square actually worked, though I've been told by a nonagenarian that it once did tell the time.

**once** means "at one time (in the past)". The modern spelling **o-n-c-e**  partially obscures the fact that the word comes from the word "one".  It used to be spelled **o-n-e-s**.

The indefinite article is used to refer to *a* stretch of time, a period of time, or an occasion, as in the clock example above, "I can't remember a time when ...".  In children's stories (as distinct from historical fiction), it is used to refer *vaguely* to a time, not to a particular time-span with known starting date and ending date.

**upon** is a variant of **on**, and we still use **on** with occasions.

> We went there on Christmas.
>
> ... on her wedding day.

In order to adapt our modern use of **on** with individual days or specific occasions to a longer span of time, we just need to think of the tale's temporal setting as a stretch of time with definite but unspecified boundaries.

Comment: ... A time to every purpose...